# Pdf file from database to view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, html, view

I have **Image** column in Ms Sql Database.Pdf files are in that column.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
DatabaseEntities _ context = new DatabaseEntities();


var PdfFile = _context.FileTable.where(p=>p.Id==1).Select(s=>s.FileData).FirstOrDefault();


return view();
}
```

I select file's Byte and set it to "**var PdfFile"**

But i am not sure how can i call PdfFile in view and display inside html div in asp.net mvc ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to actually display it in a div or just open it?

Comment: thanks for answer.I need to display it in a div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have make use of ViewData. Although I'm not sure how exactly you'er gonna display the pdf but to answer the question add this in your method:

```
 ViewData["PDF"] = PDFFile;
```

and in the razor you can get it this way:

```
@var getData = ViewData["PDF"];
```

To Display it, first convert it to base64:

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String((Byte[])ViewData["PDF"])" type="application/pdf" width="500px">
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64, @System.Convert.ToBase64String((Byte[])ViewData["PDF"])" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Comment: I tried your code it did not work . do you have any idea why does not work?

Comment: PDFFile has byte so how can i display pdf file in view ?

Comment: @CMonster Interesting, I've never seen that. It works though?

Comment: It works!!! thanks but i have one more question.In below side of pdf , there are zoom in zoom out etc etc(menu).How can i hide menu ?

Comment: @user3527568: Happy I helped you, you can accept the answer if you'd like to anyways ;)

Comment: @CMonster i will open one more question for hiding below side menu in pdf file.Please check it also.