# How to open PDF that retrived from database to a specific page in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, url, controller

I have been search similar posts for this question for few days, but still did not find any thing that meets my requirements.

This is my requirement: open a PDF in binary format to a specific page when user clicks on a hyperlink in a web grid.

This is my approach:

Step 1. PDFs are saved in database in binary format. The PDFs are retrieved by unique key that can be passed by the hyperlink click. I have code working for this already.

Step 2. The page number is determined when the PDF is retrieved and text-searched. I have code working for this already.

Step 3. Open the PDF using parameter page by directing user to http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=3 (example). Because the page number can not be passed in the first hyperlink click, Now I don't know how to take user to a new page without another user interaction or create an URL ends with #page=pageNumber in Controller redirect.

I really appreciate it you could provide me any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
@{
  var yourpdfcontent = "get from your DB"
}
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(yourpdfcontent)" type="application/pdf" width="500px">
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64, @Convert.ToBase64String(yourpdfcontent)" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Refer this link [Pdf file from database to view in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035187/pdf-file-from-database-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Where should I put this piece of the code, a new razor page or the same page with the hyperlink? Also this does not allow to put the page number in the url. I have to have the page parameter at the end of the url in order to open the pdf to a certain page.